# Gatsby build deployed on digital ocean give 404 on navigation

Tags: gatsby

I have deployed the build version of my project using "gatsby build" on Digital Ocean. When I try to navigate using menu, it gives 404 page. And even some of the Bootstrapped CSS and Other CSS & JS file get missing after the build deployed.

The project works fine on local machine by "gatsby serve". But not on Digital ocean

repo : https://github.com/mahayash/SE_Frontend.git

url : http://www.squareeducation.in/

Comment: The URL you provided returns a 403 response. You probably have nginx configured incorrectly.

Comment: Did you know how to deploy gatsby application on DigitalOcean, I tried multiple ways, but I am gettting 404 error